# windowBackground Material design compatibility

Tags: android, styles, material-design, android-appcompat

I am following the Material guidelines

[image]

The problem is that windowBackground is not available below api 21 (at least that is what I think)

- Is any generic way to know in which api the attribute has been added?
- Is there any way to know which attributes you must put appart to mantain compatibility?( you can use colorPrimary in values and values-v21, but you cant use windowBackground on values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:windowBackground` has been added in API Level 1 so it's definitely available in every Android version.

In order to check whether an attribute is available for the specific API-Level you can check the [R.attr page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html) of the Android Developer site. There you can see all possible attributes as well as the API-Level in which they were added (top-right corner).